# DoesNotExist: object matching query does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-south

When I do "object_name.objects.get(id=1)" I'm getting error. Earlier also I was getting this error when id=1 but it gave back object when id=2. Then I deleted all the entries I made in hope that it will start from id=1 but now it gives error.

Can Someone explain why this is happening and what should I do ?

```
>>> from course.models import Course, Content

>>> Course.objects.get(id=1)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/vagrant/edu-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models    /manager.py", line 143, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/vagrant/edu-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models    /query.py", line 389, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, kwargs))

DoesNotExist: Course matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'id': 1}
```

Additionally object_name.object.all() gives all the things I've entered

```
>>> Course.objects.all()
[<Course: JAVA>, <Course: HTML5>]
```

Comment: it's natural, what you must do is apply the `try` and `except`, that function handle that problem

Comment: Please read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

Comment: Do this: `Course.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)` in your shell, and see the IDs that are generated for the 2 objects. You will know why `id=1` is failing

Comment: @catherine I'm a beginner can you please elaborate ? Also if you'd like to see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863979/improperly-configured-views-and-url-in-a-model-with-one-to-many-relationship) which was the original problem I was trying to sort

Comment: @karthikr dude its now giving [7,6] earlier it was [3, 2]

Comment: you are probably adding and deleting objects, hence the difference. `.get` __always__ throws errors if the id is not existent.

Answer (score 1):

The database increments the primary key every time you create an object. If you create objects with `id=1` and `id=2`, the next object will always have `id=3`, even if you delete the existing objects.

Comment: So what should I do to start from id = 1

Comment: If you are willing to lose all existing data, you could drop the database table and recreate it to start the sequence from zero. I recommend you don't worry about it. It doesn't matter if there are 'gaps' in the list of objects primary keys.

Comment: how should I drop table I'm using vagrant and virtual box. I did ./manage.py sqlclear course it gave 'BEGIN;   DROP TABLE "course_course"    DROP TABLE "course_content"     COMMIT;' Is it done ???

Comment: The [`sqlclear`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#sqlclear-appname-appname) management command doesn't actually drop the tables, it just prints the drop table statements. You need to run those statements in a database shell. Note that the above commands will drop the `Content` tables as well as the `Course` table.